# How to reset the data receive from the user to the Variable Char after Loop

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, char, do-while

`

```
    char AS = 'N';
      do
      {
        Console.Write("\nDo you want to Add another Subject[Y/N]: ");
        char add = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper());

    

    if (add == 'Y')
        {
                AS = 'Y';
        }


  } while (AS == 'N');`
```

I received a problem from the system "The string must be one character" after the loop. How can I reset the data input in variable char named "add". Thank you

Comment: What constitutes "reset"? You can set it to any other character - even a blank space, but there's no concept of "null" with a `char` unless you make it nullable. In this case you don't need to worry about it because the `add` variable is declared in the scope of the loop. My question is, why do you want to "reset" it - what are your concerns? If we don't have a complete program then we can't make a good judgement, but if this is the complete program then you have no issues.

Comment: Its not exactly clear where you think this error is from, however I'm pretty sure its because of this `Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine().ToUpper())` Console.ReadLine returns a string, not a char thats where your error is from - tbh honest I wouldn't mess around with char here, just using a string and make your life easier